# Cannot import name UploadDocumentForm

Tags: python, django, import

I think this is a pretty common mistake, should be a problem with circular imports. But I can't find the actual problem here and I get an error on line 3 views.py

I followed this tutorial: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/topics/http/file-uploads/

forms.py

```
from django import forms

class UploadDocumentForm(forms.Form):
file = forms.FileField(label='Select a file',
help_text='*.odt only')
```

views.py

```
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect
from django.shortcuts import render_to_response
from .forms import UploadDocumentForm

# Create your views here.

def upload_document(request):
if request.method == 'POST':
    form = UploadDocumentForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
    if form.is_valid():
        return HttpResponseRedirect('/success/url/')
else:
    form = UploadDocumentForm()
return render_to_response('upload.html', {'form': form})
```

Thank you for you help!

EDIT:

```
    Traceback:
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in get_response
  101.                 resolver_match = resolver.resolve(request.path_info)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/urlresolvers.py" in resolve
  337.             for pattern in self.url_patterns:
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/urlresolvers.py" in url_patterns
  365.         patterns = getattr(self.urlconf_module, "urlpatterns", self.urlconf_module)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/urlresolvers.py" in urlconf_module
  360.             self._urlconf_module = import_module(self.urlconf_name)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/utils/importlib.py" in import_module
  40.         __import__(name)
File "/home/bla/dev/blubb/nope/nope/urls.py" in <module>
  12.     url(r'^nope_app/', include('nope_app.urls')),
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/conf/urls/__init__.py" in include
  26.         urlconf_module = import_module(urlconf_module)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/utils/importlib.py" in import_module
  40.         __import__(name)
File "/home/bla/dev/blubb/nope/nope_app/urls.py" in <module>
  3. import views
File "/home/bla/dev/blubb/nope/nope_app/views.py" in <module>
  3. from .forms import UploadDocumentForm

Exception Type: ImportError at /
Exception Value: cannot import name UploadDocumentForm
```

Comment: What's the error message, traceback?

Comment: Do you have ab __init__.py file in this app? Do they contain an import to forms.py?

Comment: I do have an __init__.py, but I don't import forms there. "from forms import *" throws the same error unfortunately,

Comment: Do you have an app named forms? Which module is imported if you do open `./manage.py shell` and `import forms`?

Comment: Nope, no app namend "forms". Can't import forms from the manage.py shell

Comment: which version of Python are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I changed the name from UploadDocumentForm to UploadFileForm, which somehow solved the problem.